# How can JVMTI agent set a JVM flag on startup?

Tags: java, jvm, jvmti

In order to support better profiling data I would like my JVMTI agent to enable a couple of JVM flags.
The agent in question is [Honest-Profiler](https://github.com/RichardWarburton/honest-profiler) and it is can only be loaded at startup.

I would like to enable the flags: `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+DebugNonSafepoints`

As per issue documented [here](https://github.com/RichardWarburton/honest-profiler/issues/132) if the flags are not on we get a biased profile. It would be good to go beyond warning the user and just enable the flag.

Comment: If you will not found legal solution, there is gory approach from @apangin: https://github.com/odnoklassniki/one-elf/blob/master/test/one/jvm/HotspotFlags.java it founds address of loaded libjvm.so and calculates flag address from .so address + .symtab constant offset (but it not always works, depends on concrete flag usage in VM code)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As to `DebugNonSafepoints` you don't even need to set this flag. Look at [debugInfoRec.cpp](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/f96d42d605e1/src/share/vm/code/debugInfoRec.cpp#l82):

```
static inline bool compute_recording_non_safepoints() {
  if (JvmtiExport::should_post_compiled_method_load()
      && FLAG_IS_DEFAULT(DebugNonSafepoints)) {
    // The default value of this flag is taken to be true,
    // if JVMTI is looking at nmethod codes.
    // We anticipate that JVMTI may wish to participate in profiling.
    return true;
  }

  // If the flag is set manually, use it, whether true or false.
  // Otherwise, if JVMTI is not in the picture, use the default setting.
  // (This is true in debug, just for the exercise, false in product mode.)
  return DebugNonSafepoints;
}
```

If the flag is not set, debug info is still recorded when JVMTI [CompiledMethodLoad](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#CompiledMethodLoad) notifications are enabled. You just need to request `can_generate_compiled_method_load_events` capability and turn on `JVMTI_EVENT_COMPILED_METHOD_LOAD` notifications.

That's exactly how I handle it in my [`async-profiler`](https://github.com/apangin/async-profiler) project.

---

There is no safe way to change unmanageable JVM flags in run-time. However, there is an ugly hack to do this on Linux.

1. Read `/proc/self/maps` to find the base address of `libjvm.so`.
2. Use [ELF format reader](https://github.com/odnoklassniki/one-elf) to discover an offset of the desired symbol in the dynamic library.
3. Write directly to the address of this symbol.

Here is [a sample code](https://github.com/odnoklassniki/one-elf/blob/master/test/one/jvm/HotspotFlags.java) for this trick.

Comment: I had managed it via Helfy (and also with Hotspot SA). I will show it with sample code when I have prepared it

Comment: here it is https://github.com/serkan-ozal/jvm-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/tr/com/serkanozal/jvm/playground/ChangeImmutableVmFlagDemo.java

Comment: @SerkanÖzal Cool! Didn't think Helfy could be used for that. Would you mind adding this example to Helfy repo on github?

Comment: sure @apangin, if you want I can send a PR :)

Comment: @SerkanÖzal Sure, go ahead and create PR. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is not a precise answer but more of a nudge in certain direction ....

In `services/writeableFlags.hpp` there are static methods for setting VM flags. The success will depend on whether these flags are actually mutable but it would be the good place to start poking around. I haven't tried calling these methods from JVMTI agent but, theoretically, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of JVM flags which can be written at runtime using `com.sun.management.HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.setVMOption`.

(For a list see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/hotspot/file/b92c45f2bc75/src/share/vm/runtime/globals.hpp and search for `manageable`).

Unfortunately for your use case the option `UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions` is not writable.